# Chrome jquery onchange counterup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

https://jsfiddle.net/76mwc1pe/

```
$('#xnumber').change(function() {   
if ( $('#ynumber').val()  < $('#xnumber').val() ) 
{ 
        $('#ynumber').val($('#xnumber').val());   
}
} );
```

If you go in xnumber field and use up arrow on your keyboard, should see ynumber that grow equally to xnumber.

This goes fine with values:

> 1)from 1 to 9, then must manually go to ynumber and force it to 11
>   value.
>
> 2)also works until 99, then again must change to 101 manually.
>
> 3)over 101, no problem you can grow without problems.

Why points 1) and 2)?

Tested with Chrome, Firefox doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/), you are accessing string values not integers. If you convert the values to integer it works as you would expect although you do need a starting value in `#xnumber`:

```
$('#xnumber').change(function() {

    if ( parseInt($('#ynumber').val(), 10)  <= parseInt($('#xnumber').val(), 10)    ) 
    { 
            $('#ynumber').val($('#xnumber').val());   
    }

    } );
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/76mwc1pe/4/

Why did I set the input with `xnumber` id to 0? Because if we call `parseInt('', 10)` it will return [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) or "Not a Number". You can handle this issue by having an additional check in the `if`.

The second parameter to `parseInt` is the radix or base (and we're using base 10 of course).

MDN: [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: One thing to note is that parseInt() will return NaN if the field is empty. In your fiddle you fixed this by using value=0 as default for the y-field, which works in this case. However "(parseInt($('#ynumber').val()) || 0)" might be a better choice since the field would not require a default value and always default to 0 for NaN values.